# How to interact with a contract function through another contract?

Tags: solidity, multisignature

I have this function on my MultiSigWallet

```
function submitTransaction(address destination, uint value, bytes data)
    public
    returns (uint transactionId)
{
    transactionId = addTransaction(destination, value, data);
    confirmTransaction(transactionId);
}
```

I want to use this to send a transaction to another contract and interface with a function. How do I prepare the `data` field ahead of time to make sure it works?

The idea behind this, is I want to have children contracts owned by this MultiSigWallet where I submit transactions to interact with the child contract which need approval by signers of the multisig.

Comment: can you add, your contracts and web3 code for this.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out how to do it!

Using web3 and having the contract ABI.

`var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);`

`var myCallData = myContractInstance.myMethod.getData(param1 [, param2, ...]);`

You can then use the `myCallData` as a parameter passed to the `submitTransaction` function on the multisig contract.